# ODataModel.resetChanges error: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: sapui5

I have created an app that runs perfectly from Web IDE. I deployed it to the Launchpad and when I call it from there I get an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at f._bindNewContext (Component-preload.js:10)
>       at f. (Component-preload.js:10)

There must be some mistake in `_bindNewContext`:

```js
_bindNewContext: function () {
  this.getModel().resetChanges().then(function() {
    this.oContext = this.getModel().createEntry("/Kardex01Set", {
      success: this._successSave.bind(this),
      error: this._errorSave.bind(this)
    })
  }.bind(this));
  // ... some more code
},
```

Is there a mistake in this coding? What else could be the reason for this error when calling the app from launchpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v2ODataModel.resetChanges()` returns a [promise **only since 1.65.0**](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/eb8dee86823e185ef7b9f241e1246f7a856820e0).
In previous versions, it returned `undefined`.

I.e. in Web IDE, you've been developing with a newer UI5 version whereas apps launched from FLP operate with an old version, hence the error.

Comment: Many thanks! This will the issue. SAP system is of version 1.60.20. So I can call resetChanges() and afterwards (without then) createEntry()?

Comment: @Julia Should be ok. According to the commit message, the purpose of the promise was to be able to deal with the remaining deferred requests too. If it doesn't apply to you, I don't see a problem calling `createEntry` right away.